# How to fix missing assets in cocoapods

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods

I am creating a cocoapod sdk and i assets are missing here is my podspec file:

`s.resource_bundles = {
     'Project' => ['Project/Assets/*.xcassets']
   }`

I also get this warning whenever i try to load the asset

`CUIThemeStore: No theme registered with id=0`

Code i am using to access the asset:

`image.image = UIImage(named: "Rectangle")`

I have tried to check my asset file target membership and it is correct it is set to   `Project-Project`

Comment: Please show the code you're using to access these assets.

Comment: @Gereon Updated

Answer (score 0):

Try accessing your assets from their own bundle explicitly:

```
final class Project: NSObject {
   private static let frameworkBundle = Bundle(for: Project.self)
   static let path = frameworkBundle.path(forResource: "Project", ofType: "bundle")!
   static let bundle = Bundle(path: path)!
}

extension UIImage {
  /// get an image from the project bundle
  static func fromPodBundle(_ name: String) -> UIImage? {
    return UIImage(named: name, in: Project.bundle, compatibleWith: nil)
  }
}

image.image = UIImage.fromPodBundle("Rectangle")
```

Comment: Still the same thing

Comment: It is also crashing here `static let path = frameworkBundle.path(forResource: "Media", ofType: "xcassets")!`

Comment: There is no Bundle called "Media.xcassets" in the compiled app. Updated my answer to show what works in my app's code.